# How can I Add a Character Space after the Date function in PHP

Tags: php, date, character

I know if I'm concatenating strings in php I can use the . operator with a empty set of quotes ' ', but how do I concatenate a space on the end of a function in php?

In the code below I want to add a single character space after the date function inside the php delimiters so there is a space between the date and the company name.  I don't want to use &nbsp in the HTML.

```
<span id="footer-year"><p><?php echo date(Y); ?></p></span><p>The Company Name</p></div>
```

Comment: Then just type a space ` ` after `?>` It is the same thing.  Is this a typo question?  Seems low value to me.  (Obsidian does offer good advice though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just echo it out with concatenation:

```
<?php echo date('Y') . " "; ?>
```

Note that you need quotes around your `Y` in **[`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)**.

Also note that a **[`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)** tag **cannot** reside within a **[`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)** tag, as `<span>` is *inline* and `<p>` is *block*-level. That would result in invalid markup. You can validate your markup with the **[W3C Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org)**.

What you're **probably** looking for is:

```
<span id="footer-year"><?php echo date('Y') . " The Company Name" ?></span>
```

Which will be **[outputted](https://3v4l.org/kUaLE)** as:

```
<span id="footer-year">2017 The Company Name</span>
```

Hope this helps :)